# Installing python and relevant packages in a PC with no internet

Tags: python, windows, installation

I need to install python and all the relevant packages like "numpy" etc in a Windows PC that is not connected to the internet. Can I do this by downloading relevant things from python website to a pen drive and then installing? If yes, please suggest on how this can be done. If no, kindly suggest any other methodologies that can be followed.

I haven't tried anything but would like to know the feasibility of using a pen drive or DVD for installation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done!

On PyPi, you have the option to download tar.gz files (Here is the one for [NumPy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files))

To install it, you can use `pip install <path-to-package>`

Answer (score 0):

You can download binaries directly from official [pypi](https://pypi.org/) and install that zip files like so
Example search like ["numpy pypi"](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files)

[image]

Go to download on left

[image]

For windows

```
numpy-1.24.2-pp38-pypy38_pp73-win_amd64.whl
```

you can clearly see on the name of the file there will be `win` For windows and for linux there will be `linux`

Then install binaries like

```
pip install path/to/downloads/dummy_library_name.tar.gz
```

you can variety of files

Comment: I tried ur suggestion and used  to install pyaedt-0.6.70.tar.gz. This is working only if there's internet connection. Is there anyway where I can install without internet?
I have also downloaded a wheelhouse file. Please suggest if this could be used for offline installation.